# Installing cuda toolkit Ubuntu 14.04 causes dpkg error

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, cuda

When I was installing cuda toolkit Ubuntu 14.04 causes `dpkg` error.

This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

However I get this error from `dpkg`:

```
dpkg-deb: error: cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb (--install):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-split: error: error reading .: Is a directory
dpkg: error processing archive . (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2

Errors were encountered while processing:
 cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the name. Can you try with these steps
1) `cp cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb cuda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7.0_28_amd64.deb`
2) `sudo dpkg -i cuda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7.0_28_amd64.deb`

Comment: i am in same directory and I have tested this:1) cp cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb cuda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7.0_28_amd64.deb 2) sudo dpkg -i cuda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7.0_28_amd64.deb but i have the error again

Comment: sorry, I mean `cp cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb cuda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7_0_28_amd64.deb` 2) `sudo dpkg -i cuda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7_0_28_amd64.deb`. The whole point is to replace every `-` or `.` in the file name with an underscore.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you verify the integrity of that file? Run `md5sum cuda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7_0_28_amd64.deb` and compare the result to `9c74b64c8f453a5a907959c29fc0097c` ([source](//a248.e.akamai.net/f/862/5658/3/developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7_0/Prod/md5sum-7.0.txt)). The output of `file uda_repo_ubuntu1404_7_0_local_7_0_28_amd64.deb` may also give us a hint to the nature of that file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're in the same directory as the .deb file and that you're using the right file name for the dpkg command.